# SignalR and IIS recycle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

i want to create a server that send notifications to client using SignalR - using groups
suppose that my site was recycled - what will happen to the groups as they are not persist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to persist your groups in external permanent storage. Look for more details here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/working-with-groups

Comment: By default, SignalR automatically re-assigns a user to the appropriate groups when reconnecting from a temporary disruption, such as when a connection is dropped and re-established before the connection times out. The user's group information is passed in a token when reconnecting, and that token is verified on the server. For information about the verification process for rejoining users to groups, see Rejoining groups when reconnecting.

Comment: also is it possible for a client to register to several groups?

Comment: Yes the rejoining is only applicable when you reconnect from temporary disruptions. But if the site is recycled or the app domain restarts, groups will not be persisted. Yes, a client can be a part of multiple groups.